# How to fix 502 Bad Gateway NGINX error while deploying a django app on AWSEB command line?

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bad-gateway

I have been trying to deploy a Django application on `awsebcli`. immediately I enter the `eb` open command I get *502 Bad Gateway NGINX* error in return on my web browser. Please I need assistance on how to fix this error, for a better view and understanding my codes screenshots are in the upload links as follows.

**`settings.py`**

[image: 1]

**`502 Bad Gateway`**

[image: 2]

**`.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`**

[image: 3]

**`.ebextensions\django.config`**

[image: 4]

**`aswebcli status`**

[image: 5]

**`pip freeze`** command result

[image: 6]

I look forward to your kind response. Thank you

Comment: Can you post the log file from eb

Comment: What about port and name of the starting application python file? THey are set correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your response so far. I finally figured it out. Python 3.7 Amazon Linux 2 platform on elastic beanstalk uses gunicorn as a web server gateway interface (wsgi). It makes the operation of the Django app on the server flexible and faster. I installed gunicorn and added it to the Django installed app under settings.py. i also included it in the requirements.txt for identification. Finally I created a procfile containing "web: gunicorn--bind :8000 --workers 3 --threads 2:<appname>.wsgi: application"  I deployed into eb and open. NGINX 502 bad gateway error is no more. That settles it.

Comment: @EmmanuelOyovwikigho i am having the same issue, can you guide more on how you solved it?

Comment: You can refer to this answer for help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67217962/12617787

Answer (score 3):

**Check the file `web.stdout.log`**; it should tell you what the error was.  You can access this by downloading the EB logs, or by running `eb ssh` and finding it in the `/var/log/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that Python 3.7+ on Amazon Linux 2 platform needs gunicorn. In my case I only needed to pip install gunicorn and add it in requirements.txt. I did not need to edit the setting.py file. Also my django.config looks like below:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application
```

Reference: [AWS documentation on deploying Django with Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-update-app)

Comment: Kind of weird how the tutorial documentation doesn't state this. Also some tutorials I've found in youtube didn't necessarily did this and still worked out for them. This did the trick if ever some people had trouble with 502 bad gateway

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.7 Amazon Linux 2 platform for ebs firstly install gunicorn then add it to your requirements.txt and edit the django.config file to

```
option_settings: 
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment": 
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "elernet.settings" 
    "PYTHONPATH": "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python": 
    WSGIPath: elernet.wsgi:application 
    NumProcesses: 3 
    NumThreads: 20
```

eb deploy 
eb open

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue using the elastic beanstalk python-3.8 platform and Django 3.2.  It's worth noting that the 502 error from nginx will occur with a few different deployment errors (mine were occurring during the `manage.py migrate` command).  Despite fixing the issues suggested in other comments, the 502 error persisted for me.

Ultimately, it was because I was running into some version issues with SQLite and the Amazon Linux 2 platform.  I switched to postgres and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the below step worked.

1. Run `eb config` command.
2. It opens up the file. Look for  `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:`
3. If it has application, change it to `elernet.wsgi:application`